# Is a separate Python instance started for each instance of a Django application via Apache?

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm a little confused as to how Apache manages separate "instances" of a Django application.

Let's say I do the following:

- Go to the URL of my Django application
- Open up a new browser tab
- In the new tab, also go to the URL of my Django application

Are two Python instances started, one for each browser tab?

The application contains a form that a user fills out. After they submit the form, a POST request is sent back to the view. The view then calls another function to do something with the POST data. Let's say I do that in the first browser tab.

While that function is running, if I submit the form now in the second browser tab, will running that function be blocked until the function is done running in the first tab? Or are separate Python instances started?

I'm just trying to figure out if I need to start a separate process each time the function is called from the view, in order to support multiple "instances" of the application (e.g., either in separate browser tabs or multiple users accessing the application simultaneously).

Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these things.

Depending on how your server is configured, it will start up multiple processes and/or threads to handle multiple requests. Each of those will handle a single request at a time; however each process stays alive at the end of a request and continues to run in order to handle subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you outlined there should be one instance of Django running on the server. It just happens to be managing two sessions.